# web2py Tk library not installed

Tags: python, tkinter, web2py

I am using python 2.7 and I would like to do some web2py stuff. I am trying to run web2py from eclipse and I am getting the following error trying to run web2py.py script:

WARNING:web2py:GUI not available because Tk library is not installed

I am running on Windows 7 (64 bit).

Any suggestions?

Thank you

Comment: Do you have Tk installed? Does it work from outside eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have to first install TK on Windows. You can obtain all the details [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html#installwin). Essentially, you'll have to go to [www.activestate.com](http://www.activestate.com) and follow the links to download the Community Edition  of Active Tcl for Windows (version 8.5.x).

Comment: installed it and I still get the same error.Should I installed it in a specific folder in Python dir somewhere?

Comment: @Yebach Did you also download and install the _Community Edition of ActivePython for Windows_? (same link)

Comment: I am trying to install it but the installer is not working. It stops while determining my disk requirements. Like WTF?!"# I read smth. about uninstalling Python 2.7. I ain't doing that

Comment: So at the end I had to uninstall python and install it again. seems like i had mixed versions of 32-bit and 64bit. I works now

Answer (score 0):

If you trying web2py on Ubuntu using python3, install using

```
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

Comment: Question is about python 2.7 and windows not python3 and ubuntu!

Comment: perhaps not the OP's same situation, but I am trying web2py on a WSL2 instace. Before installing `python3-tk` I was just getting the warning but web2py was still launching. After installing `python3-tk` it no longer launches. When I `CTRL-C` twice I see this error: `_tkinter.TclError: couldn't connect to display "172.25.96.1:0"`. In order for graphics to work in WSL2 Ubuntu 20.04 I have added this to my `.bashrc`: `export DISPLAY=$(awk '/nameserver / {print $2; exit}' /etc/resolv.conf 2>/dev/null):0`, which works for other applications. Any suggestions for a fix?

Comment: actually, dumb me, I forgot to start the vcx server on Windows first. After running `xlaunch` and adding the `-ac` parameter as some suggest on the forums, I now get the web2py interface.